# Закругление углов картинки с прозрачностью

Tags: css

Есть следующая картинка:

[image]

Что смущает... Надо реализовать зеленый фон у картинки... Да ещё и чтоб все углы были закруглены у картинки, да ещё и чтоб закругленные углы были прозрачными - потому как фон сайта идет градиентом...

Картинки планируются загружаться обыкновенные, без заранее закругленных углов.

Comment: [Оформление изображений на CSS3](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/css/129313/)

Answer (score 1):

Spectre прав. Здесь нужно использовать css3. Если поддержка данных красот в ие обязательна, то лучше использовать для него css3pie или что-то похожее.

Саму тень сделайте как обычно - спрайт из пнг + верхний/нижний уголок с абсолютным позиционированием и фиксированными размерами, боковую тень замостить по вертикали, блок будет растягиваться в зависимости от размера картинки. К самой картинке применить скругление углов. Должно получиться.

Answer (score 1):

Из css3:

```
border-radius - закругление
box-shadow - тень
```

но только в последних браузерах